# Detect touch of CCSprite (included in an array) dragging the finger on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'm new to cocos2d and I'm developing a game where identical objects (like Fruit Ninja) fall in continuous and the user must catch them both with a touch either by dragging the finger across the screen. 
I tried creating an NSMutableArray to which I add a sprite every time I create it and it falls down, but I realize that it detects that I touched a sprite even if it isn't true, seems that the sprite is invisible.
when I touched the sprite I remove it, but it probably does not remove it.
Here is my code:

```
@interface GameScene : CCScene
{
    NSMutableArray *spriteArray;
}

- (id)init
{
    spriteArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return self;
}

- (void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    [self schedule:@selector(addSprites:) interval:1.0];
}


- (void)addSprites:(CCTime)dt
{
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"sprite000.png"];

    int minX = sprite.contentSize.width / 2;
    int maxX = self.contentSize.width - sprite.contentSize.width / 2;
    int rangeX = maxX - minX;
    int randomX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;

    sprite.position = CGPointMake(randomX, self.contentSize.height + sprite.contentSize.height);
    [self addChild:sprite z:6];
    [spriteArray addObject:sprite];

    CCAction *actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:3.0 position:CGPointMake(randomX, -sprite.contentSize.height)];

    CCAction *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];
    [sprite runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove, actionRemove]]];

    if ([spriteArray count] > 50) 
    {
        [spriteArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 40)]];
    }
}


-(void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];

    for (CCSprite *sprite in spriteArray)
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], touchLoc))
        {
            CCLOG(@"Touched!");
            CCAction *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];
            [sprite runAction:actionRemove];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not removing the sprite from the spriteArray. So you will check for touches with the removed sprites, too. Try

```
for (int i=0;i<spriteArray.count;i++)
{
    //get the current sprite from the array
    CCSprite *sprite = [spriteArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], touchLoc))
    {
        CCLOG(@"Touched!");
        CCAction *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];
        [sprite runAction:actionRemove];

        //remove the sprite from the array
        [spriteArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];

        //decrement i to be safe if you remove the return one day
        --i;

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Good to know its deprecated now, so I removed it from my answer.